# angular way to use number with comma and dot to calculate another value

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularJS and Angular Material Design.

For one of the amount field i have input box as below which displays calculated field.

Whenever the value is stored it is stored as comma separated i.e. `19,999.9984` which is not a problem for me.

But whenever i use this value for another calculation, i get NaN.

`$scope.txn.toUnits = $scope.txn.toAmount / $scope.txn.toPrice`

Above expression end up with NaN since there is a comma in toAmount value `19,999.9984`

Is there any angular way to resolve this ?

Comment: one solution comes to my mind. you could make it a string and then do a replace and make it a number again. you can take a look here - https://jsfiddle.net/k1Lfbx55/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the parseFloat function

Answer (score 1):

This is a best solution to do this if it interests you :

http://numeraljs.com/